# 64 bit Delphi android application was not running in 32 bit mobiles

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using Delphi 10.3.3. As per the Google Policy, all the new android apps should be 64 bit. So, I have uploaded the 64 bit android application.

After this few mobiles was not able to run the 64 bit app. IS there any possible was to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes, use app bundle and provide both 32bit and 64bit version of your application. [Submitting Your Android App to Google Play](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Submitting_Your_Android_App_to_Google_Play)

Comment: I'm trying to generate the .apk file by enabling Generate Android App Bundle file (arm + arm64) option, but I'm getting error message -     **c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\20.0\bin\CodeGear.Deployment.targets(872,5): error : Error: E0002 Missing profile name; use paclient -? for Help** 
[Done] building target "__StripOutputFiles" in project "Project1.dproj" -- FAILED. Any idea to resolve this issue? [error](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/E0002_Missing_profile_name)